# Matching multiple instances of pattern in string

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to save helper strings (kind of like Stack's `[enter link description here][1]`) to the database and compile them as HTML when retrieved/viewed. A sample text is:

```
var str = 'This is just a sample text followed by an {{image: imageUrl1}}. And here is another {{image: imageUrl2}}.';
```

I tried the following RegEx:

```
str.match(`/(\{\{image:)[^(.*\}\})]*.*(\}\})/g`);
```

But I just get `["{{image: imageUrl1}}. And here is another {{image: imageUrl2}}"]`.

What should be the RegEx pattern so that the result is `["{{image: imageUrl1}}", "{{image: imageUrl2}}"]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regex is greedy(matches all possible results to satisfy the condition). That means, the regex will match the string from `{{` to the last `}}`. To match only until the first `}}` symbols, make it lazy by adding `?` quantifier after the `*` quantifier.

```
/{{image:[^}]*?}}/g
```

Here's live [demo](https://regex101.com/r/ZrTcNM/2) on RegEx101

**Explanation:**

1. `{{image:`: Match `{{image:` literal
2. `[^}]*?`: Match anything but `}` lazily
3. `}}`: Match `}}` literals

Note that surrounding the regex by back-ticks makes it string. Use the regex literal syntax.

```js
var str = 'This is just a sample text followed by an {{image: imageUrl1}}. And here is another {{image: imageUrl2}}.';

var matches = str.match(/{{image:[^}]*?}}/g);
console.log(matches);
```

---

To extract the URL, use the capturing group and get the first captured group.

```
/{{image:\s*([^}]*?)}}/
```

```js
var str = 'This is just a sample text followed by an {{image: http://someURLHERE.domain}}. And here is another {{image: imageUrl2}}.';

var regex = /{{image:\s*([^}]*?)}}/g;
var match = '';
var urls = [];

while (match = regex.exec(str)) {
    urls.push(match[1]);
}

console.log(urls);
```

Comment: what does `greedy` mean?

Comment: @dork Please see [What do lazy and greedy mean in the context of regular expressions?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2301285/what-do-lazy-and-greedy-mean-in-the-context-of-regular-expressions)